# Get Table Name based on the column name and value

Tags: php, mysqli

My table is admin and user with columns (id,username,name,password) with values inside.

```
Table admin:  id=1  username=awesome  name=awesome  password=  password 

Table user:  id=1  username=user  name=user  password=  password
```

Now i want to know the name of table with username=awesome. Any script for that?

Comment: You should store all the users in the user table, then either have a column or another table with user roles.

Comment: What if both tables had a user with the same username? If you want to find out if a user is an admin based on the username you should be using only one table with an is_admin flag or something similar. Otherwise it will be hard to prevent users from registering with a username already taken by an admin.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there's a script to show the TABLE NAME with username=awesome.

Comment: yeah, [Barmar gave you an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45990428/1415724). That to me looks like a solution and the question should be marked as solved by accepting his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` query;

```
SELECT 'admin' AS tablename
FROM admin 
WHERE username = 'awesome'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'user' AS tablename
FROM user
WHERE username = 'awesome'
```